# Check an array against another with performance

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I got an initial array, I am checking against another array to find how many objects have at least one instance of the `Domain` in data.

This works but it performs very poorly when there is a lot of data.

```js
const data = [
  {
    Domain: 'google.com',
    '# Reocurring Domains': 0
  },
  {
    Domain: 'apple.com',
    '# Reocurring Domains': 0
  },
  {
    Domain: 'facebook.com',
    '# Reocurring Domains': 0
  }
]

const domains = [
  {
    'google.com': true,
    'microsoft.com': true,
    'google.com': true
  },
  {
    'apple.com': true,
    'microsoft.com': true,
    'twitter.com': true
  },
  {
    'facebook.com': true,
    'apple.com': true,
    'facebook.com': true
  }
]

for (const obj of data) {
  let count = 1
  for (const entry of domains) {
    if (entry[obj.Domain]) {
      obj['# Reocurring Domains'] = count++
    }
  }
}

console.log(data)
```

In there any way to this with a more performant approach?

Thanks.

Comment: what does your domains array indicate? What's it's cardinality?

Comment: Domains array is just a way to put all the domains in a list that I can check against the data domains

Comment: When you have working code, but look for performance improvements, then the question is more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through first and index the domains

```js
const domains = [
  {
    'google.com': true,
    'microsoft.com': true,
    'google.com': true
  },
  {
    'apple.com': true,
    'microsoft.com': true,
    'twitter.com': true
  },
  {
    'facebook.com': true,
    'apple.com': true,
    'facebook.com': true
  }
]

const domainIndex = {};
for (const entry of domains) {
    for(const domain of Object.keys(entry))
        domainIndex[domain] = (domainIndex[domain] || 0) +1 
}
console.log(domainIndex);
```

This will make it much quicker when trying to look up how many domains for each element in your `data` array as there is no longer a need for a nested loop.

```js
const data = [
  {
    Domain: 'google.com',
    '# Reocurring Domains': 0
  },
  {
    Domain: 'apple.com',
    '# Reocurring Domains': 0
  },
  {
    Domain: 'facebook.com',
    '# Reocurring Domains': 0
  }
]

const domains = [
  {
    'google.com': true,
    'microsoft.com': true,
    'google.com': true
  },
  {
    'apple.com': true,
    'microsoft.com': true,
    'twitter.com': true
  },
  {
    'facebook.com': true,
    'apple.com': true,
    'facebook.com': true
  }
]
const domainIndex = {};
for (const entry of domains) {
    for(const domain of Object.keys(entry))
        domainIndex[domain] = (domainIndex[domain] || 0) +1 
}

for (const obj of data) {
    obj['# Reocurring Domains'] = domainIndex[obj.Domain] 
}
 console.log(data);
```

It is important to note that with this solution that it separates indexing the data from looking up the data. When comparing to your original you shouldn't include the time taken to index (which only needs to be done once when you get the `domain` data).

Performance comparison (Note indexing done as part of setup is intentional!): https://jsbench.me/49kl892vlf/1

Comment: It's funny, when I run your suggestion with a lot more data, it takes longer than the original

Comment: @Álvaro can you create a codesandbox or jsfiddle with more data so I can take a look? This _should_ perform better

Comment: It's gonna be very difficult as I am running in an express route with socket.io, I am still investigating is probably something wrong with my implementation

Comment: @Álvaro I made a few changes, forgetting that for raw performance you want to avoid any of the callback type methods like `flatMap and `reduce` in favour of simple loops. And note what I wrote at the end, including perf comparison - this is many times faster

Comment: Hey I have noticed that the jsbench was wrongly written, if we put it right, my original still faster https://jsbench.me/7lkl9a1bf5/1

Comment: @Álvaro I was assuming you got the `domain` info once, and then used it multiple times to fill in the `data`. In which case you index it once, and use it multiple times. If you get the domain info once, and have to only use it once to fill in data then your original way is perhaps the better way.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can replace the inner loop using a filter function

```
for (const obj of data) {
  
  const filteredDomains = domains.filter((entry)=>{
      // code for filtering
     })
 
  obj['# Reocurring Domains'] = filteredDomains.length


}
```

Comment: Whether you filter or loop the performance will be broadly the same. Perhaps slightly worse using filter as it has an extra method call for every element.